# MySQL Query in PHP doesn't return full result

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this:

```
echo $user_id; // prints 3
$tags_ids_results = $mysqli->query("SELECT TagID FROM UserTagSubscriptions WHERE UserID = $user_id");
while($tag_id_row = $tags_ids_results->fetch_object()) {
    $tag_id = $tag_id_row->TagID;
    echo "In While Loop";
}
```

This only prints "In While Loop" once. However, when I run the query against the database directly (with the same value of `$user_id`), three rows are returned.

**UPDATE**

When I call `fetch_all()` on `$tags_ids_results`, I get a call to undefined method error (I'm on PHP 5.4). I also get NULL when I print out `num_row`.

Comment: Use fetch_all and print out the array.  I'm assuming your query isn't returning 3 rows as you suspect.  Otherwise you have something breaking the loop and you aren't presenting the full code.

Comment: @Devon oddly enough, I get a call to undefined method error when I use `fetch_all()`. Also when I print out `$tags_ids_results->num_row`, I get NULL.

Comment: Add an update.   You should just be doing `print_r($tags_ids_results->fetch_all());` right after the query.

Comment: var_dump($tags_ids_results); and var_dump($mysqli) then..

Comment: shouldn't you write `UserID = '$user_id'` In other words you should wrap the UserID value in single quotes

Comment: @Devon This is what I get when I var_dump the results variable: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(3) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Alright, well you do have three rows and it is a mysqli_result, so you must not be using the mysqlnd (native driver) if you can't use fetch_all().  Not really a reason I can see that your loop won't run three times from what you have presented.

Comment: @Devon I'm on a Godaddy shared hosting server, so the mysql settings aren't really in my hands.

Comment: It wouldn't affect fetch_object.  So the problem is most likely in your loop is what I was saying.  Post your full code.

Comment: @Devon turns out it was indeed a problem from the rest of my loop. I had another variable with the same name as my results variable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was redeclaring `$tags_ids_results` in the rest of my loop.